# How is Windows Update service triggered/started in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

In Windows 7 the "Windows Update" service is set to "Automatic (Delayed Start)" but on Windows 10 Home it is set to Manual (Trigger Start).

What is the trigger that starts the service?

Looking around, I've found a couple of tasks in "Task Scheduler" under Microsoft->Windows Update folder. ***Are these it <s>and since I've changed them, how can they be recreated/reset</s>?***

EDIT: 
The tasks I refer to above having nothing to do with Windows Update service but are meant to update the AppStore apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tool [Service Trigger Editor](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/ServiceTriggerEditor/) to select the WU service and look/edit the triggers for each service.

[image]

Look here which triggers are assigned for WU.